# Getting JSON from a URL

Tags: php, json, curl

I am attempting to get a JSON string and it keeps coming up NULL and I am not sure why. Can someone check to see if I got my code right?

```
$url = "http:/engin.umich.edu/college/about/cal/event-calendar/futurejson";
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
     $feed = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($feed,true);
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `$feed` ?

Comment: Can you post the result of `curl_error($ch)`? You can put that after the line `$feed = curl_exec($ch);`. It will tell you if there were problems fetching the url.

Comment: You have a typo in the URL, it should begin `http://` -- you're missing one of the slashes. You also need to enable the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option, because it returns a redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $url = "http://engin.umich.edu/college/about/cal/event-calendar/futurejson";
 // missing /  ^
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
 // It's returning a redirect to www.engin.umich.edu
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 $feed = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 $data = json_decode($feed,true);
```

Comment: I wonder why is it that when I go to the page in a browser its pure JSON but your telling me its a redirect? That might explain why I am getting NULL - Syntax error, malformed JSON when I fixed the // issue.

Comment: Browsers follow redirects automatically. CURL requires you to set an option for this, otherwise it returns the redirect status and you have to follow it yourself if you want.

Comment: Thanks! Fixing the URL and then dumping the result and clicking on the redirect link finally showed me where the data actually lived.